# Save layer list to GeoJSON file

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, plugins

I have a list of layers and I want to group them all into one GeoJSON file. I have tried this solution :

```py
options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
options.driverName = "geoJson"
writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layers[0], "C:/Users/ilyasse2.0/Documents/SQRLAND/hhhh.geojson", options)
options.actionOnExistingFile = QgsVectorFileWriter.CreateOrOverwriteLayer
for l in layers:
    writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(l, "C:/Users/ilyasse2.0/Documents/SQRLAND/hh.geojson",options)
    print(writer)
```

but I get this error :

'Overwriting of existing layer failed (OGR error: DeleteLayer() not supported by this dataset.

Comment: It seems that you are trying to overwrite a GeoJSON file, so delete an existing one and create a new with the same name. That is not supported with GeoJSON files and that is probably even not what you want to do. You would like to open an existing GeoJSON file and append new data into that. You can find examples about how to append data with plain GDAL python from https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/ogr/ogr_geojson.py.

Comment: Your solution is using the GDAL Python API. You can use the PyQGIS API. Maybe you should call the Processing algorithm (the Processing toolbox) to merge first ?

Comment: Easier solution to my opinion. Combine all `layers` into one by standard `processing` script or just copy all features into a new virtual layer. Then write it into a geojson file.